# Изменение названия приложения под иконкой

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

Как переименовать название приложения? Я перешел в манифест увидел эту строчку        `android:label="@string/app_name"`, затем перешел в `strings`, там изменил `app_name` на новое. Но при последующем запуске приложения на устройстве название под иконкой осталось прежним. Как изменить название приложения?

Comment: Вообще, так и изменять. Возможно, у вас стоит локализация, где вы название не поменяли. Возможно, у вас проект собрался криво или не собрался вовсе. Посмотрите в эти стороны.

Comment: @Jarvis_J попробывал изменить на английское название - поменлось без проблем. А на русском - ничего не меняется

Comment: В манифесте надо меня в теге application application android:label="@string/bhhh

Comment: @Романыч зачем? Если я изменяю значение в файле `strings.xml` ?

Comment: Не видя проекта сложно сказать. Попробуйте clean + rebuild

Comment: @Felay это я к тому, что в теге application , android:label может ссылаться на что то другой чем допустим android:label в корневой активити. И если приложение локализовано , то файлов string.xml может быть несколько

Comment: @Романыч понял. После того как я в третий раз пересобрал проект каким то чудом приложение все таки изменило свое название на нужное, алилуя